# Clean Up OpenProj

Tags: 12.04

For the usual reasons I tried to install open project, a rpm package using alien as follows,

sudo alien openproj-1.4-2.noarch.rpm 
dpkg -i openproj_1.4-3_all.deb

which didn't work because of the need for a different flavour of java to the one that is installed on my ubuntu 12.04.

Using a similar procedure I installed projectlibre.  Everything worked fine.

My question ... how do I remove and clean up openproj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have converted the rpm package to a deb package, so you have to use the dpkg to uninstall.

> sudo dpkg -r OpenProj

Answer (score 0):

to run properly OpenProj you must config next

Open $HOME/.openproj/run.conf and Change

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx768m"

To

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.vendor=Sun -Xms128m -Xmx768m"

then run it, It will work fine.

answered Apr 23 '13 at 6:59
Aalkhodiry
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681765/openproj-java-exe-error-on-linux